# PyCharm doesn't recognize iterator and enumerator return types

Tags: iterator, pycharm, enumerate, type-hinting

Consider the following example of a very simple iterator:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.list = [0] * n

    def __iter__(self):
        return AIter(self)
```

and

```
class AIter(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        """
        Args:
            a(A):
        """
        self.obj = a
        self.n = len(a.list)
        self.i = 0

    def __next__(self):
        if self.i == self.n:
            raise StopIteration
        else:
            self.i += 1
            return self.obj.list[self.i-1]
```

When typing in a PyCharm editor, after defining `a=A(5)`, `a.list[0].` does complete the functions for int. 
However, when using something like `for j in a:` I cannot get PyCharm to understand that j is an int. It knows that `AIter.next()` returns an int, and it knows that `A.__iter__()` returns an `AIter`.

This can be solved by writing `# type: int` after the for, 
but this seems like a workaround, and I have to remember to do this every time I call a for or enumerate. 
Can I make PyCharm recognize the correct types automatically?

Comment: It's a bug, I've filed the issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-22181

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed since February 15, 2017. The latest EAP is available [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/nextversion/).

Comment: Actually, it seems that it was only solved for the iterator but not for enumerate